# extract starting and ending with a special character

Tags: linux, shell, unix

extract starting and ending with a special character

Content from the file:

```
/genomes/date/pa341/abc.txt

/genomes/date/ha76870/xyz/a1.pdf
```

Result should be

```
/genomes/date/pa341/

/genomes/date/ha76870/xyz/
```

Comment: `xargs dirname < file.txt`

Comment: you're only removing the filename from the filepaths; try to come up with something using `sed`

Comment: @Shawn that's a wild use of `xargs` o_O

Comment: @Fravadona I like to try to think outside the box.

Comment: Comparing your input and output, all I see is stripping filename and extension. What's this about "special characters"?

Comment: @Shawn, ...try that with `/genomes/by-researcher/Firstname Lastname/123.txt` -- it'll return `/genomes/by-researcher` as one line and `Lastname` as a second one, because `xargs` when called without `-d` or `-0` operates on words (with shell-like but not fully shell-compatible parsing/splitting rules), not lines. Should at least be (with GNU xargs) `xargs -d $'\n'` dirname -- <file.txt` to split on lines only, or `tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 ...` to work with BSD xargs as well.